# getting the right week and year from a timestamp

Tags: php, sql

i have a function which gets all the newly registered users, and displays it depending on the filter given whether it is newly registered by month or by year.

on this example i am using year, i have this sql

`Select date_registered from users where date_registered > '2011-12-31 12:59:59' AND date_registered < '2013-01-01 12:00:00'`

so this will result in all `date_registered` registered for the year 2012

the question is how to be more dynamic that i may apply a filter for example 
`where date_registered > $dynamic_date and date_registered < $dynamic_date`

or any good advise how to achieve this  better.

thanks . .

Comment: Exactly like you wrote?  Just put values into the two variables (likely should be two different vars).  Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: i'm looking for something that would make it more dynamic and not me changing the variable every time the year ends ,or changes

Comment: You could use mktime and date to generate the strings.

Comment: You could check out the `YEAR()` function built in on mysql: [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/year.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a small data set, I would go the pure SQL route that Tikkes' answer shows; however, for index purposes, calculating the bounds may be better.

[mktime](http://php.net/mktime) and [date](http://php.net/date) can be used for this:

```
$lowerBound = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, -1, 1, 1, date('Y')); //1 second before 00:00:00 1 Dec <current year>
$upperBound = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, -1, 1, 1, date('Y') + 1); //1 second before 00:00:00 1 Dec <current year + 1>
```

So then you just put them in a query:

```
$sql = " ... WHERE d > '$lowerBound' AND d < '$upperBound'";
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
$sql = "SELECT date_registered 
       FROM users
       WHERE YEAR(date_registered) = YEAR(NOW())";
```

check this out for [more information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/year.html)

Since you also want the right week, also look at the function `YEARWEEK()`. It works in the same way and returns the number of the week as well. [See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$sql = "SELECT date_registered FROM users WHERE date_registered > '$dateStart' AND date_registered < '$dateEnd'";
```

where `$dateStart` and `$dateEnd` are your dynamic date variables

A pair of SINGLE quotes around your variables should be enough. All the statement string has to be in DOUBLE quotes as you see.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BETWEEN`, it's more readable.

MySQL has a great [list of date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Basically, what you want to do is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Store_Information
WHERE Date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
```

I don't know what data you're starting from, or where you get your $start and $end inputs. I'm going to assume you're using unix timestamps, generated from [time()](http://php.net/time), and then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Store_Information
WHERE Date BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME('$start') AND FROM_UNIXTIME('$end')
```

If this does not suffice, please be clearer how you format your indata ($start, $end).